# Print value from variable react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i am trying to print value of variable 'str' by setting its state. My approach is When the user click the button Print the TextInput value in the Text field. I am getting the value though using console and alert but its not printing in the desired tags

Here's my code

```
`
var str="";

class WeatherProject extends Component{

  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={
        From:'',
        To:''
    }

  }

 changeText=(From)=>{
   this.setState({From})

 }
 onPress = ()=>{
  str= this.state.From
 }
  render(){
return (
<View>
    <TextInput placeholder="From" id="from" style={styles.fromField} onChangeText={this.changeText} /> 
    <Button
      title={"Press"}
      color="#f194ff"
      onPress={this.onPress}
      ></Button>

      <Text>{str}</Text> //Here i need the output via variable str
      </View>

);
}
}

export default WeatherProject
```

`

Comment: You can directly use <Text>{this.state.From}</Text> instead of str

Comment: @b-mohammad 's answer is correct. In short, you need to change `onPress = ()=>{this.setState({To: this.state.From})}` and `<Text>{this.state.To}</Text>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put `str` as a state, i made a demo in snack:

check is here : [demo](https://snack.expo.io/HJE8B5a_U)

Comment: You have this.state.To unused. Much better of use `To` instead of `str`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the variable `str` is out of scope in the render function.

You could just use

```
      <Text>{this.state.From}</Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not referencing to state by just writing {str} inside Text. You should do :

```
<Text>{this.state.From}</Text>
```

hope it helps

Comment: But this should give me a live result. I want to handle this via variable

Comment: this.state.From is a variable which you are setting